# Remix not showing function button after successful deployment

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am trying out Solidity on Remix and I can successfully deploy contracts. However, I expect to see the function button after my deployment is done (as it contains multiple functions) but it doesn't come up : [Can't see function button after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJJCE.png). Is this browser related as I have tried multiple browsers?

As you might have seen, my functions are public as well.

Regards,

Comment: your code has this line `bool publiv myBool` publiv instead of public, yet successfully compiled?

Comment: Noticed it earlier and I have corrected it. Apparently, I observed remix doesn't auto-save, one has to manually do this, which is why I missed it also. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to compile your code before deploying first off (ctrl+s). Refreshing your browser can sometimes fix issues you have with function visibility. Only started using Remix a few days ago and experienced a similar issue - refreshing fixed for me.

Comment: This worked! I saved & refreshed and the functions are appearing now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change modifier to public and its start displaying button after deployment.